# Julia 0.0.6 LoadError on ODE solve

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I am trying to solve a simple Lotka Volterra model

```
using DifferentialEquations
f2 = @ode_def_nohes LVtest begin
  dx = x*(1.0 - A*x - B*y)
  dy = y*(rho - C*x - D*y)
end A B C D rho

u0 = [1;1]
tspan = (0.0,300.0)
p = [0.2,0.3,0.35,0.2,0.25]
prob = ODEProblem(f2,u0,tspan,p)
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())
```

This returns the error:

ERROR: LoadError: InexactError()

Comment: Notice that it says your problem is `ODEProblem with uType Array{Int64,1} and tType Float64. In-place: true`, so you've defined your state (your diffeq variables) to be integers. The state type is defined by your initial condition [as mentioned in the tutorial](http://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/tutorials/ode_example.html#Example-3:-Using-Other-Types-for-Systems-of-Equations-1), and so as mentioned below you likely want to make sure it's floats. And for reference, [there are diffeqs on integers](http://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/tutorials/discrete_stochastic_example.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic line is:

```
u0 = [1;1]
```

which produces `Vector{Int}`. Change it to:

```
u0 = [1.0,1.0]
```

or

```
u0 = Float64[1,1]
```

and all will work.